# Flutter re-run Future on navigation back

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want Flutter to re-run the `CustomerService.getCustomerInformation()` Future after it has changed the route with `Navigator.push()` and returned back to this widget with sliding. Meanwhile, I have discovered that the only way for doing so is to re-initiate the `initState()` function call, which might not be a good idea I guess. Are there any solutions to this?

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    CustomerService.getCustomerInformation().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        name = value['name'];
        loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

The `getCustomerInformation` function is a simple `static Future<dynamic>` that calls an `HttpsCallable` function, and returns JSON object as a response.

```dart
settingsTile(
          Icons.settings_outlined,
          Colors.pink,
          'Settings',
          () => {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return const SettingsBiometry();
                    },
                  ),
                )
              })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with future method, using `FutureBuilder` will be a good choice.  Also `.push` method is a future method, you can `await` for it.

```dart
settingsTile(
          Icons.settings_outlined,
          Colors.pink,
          'Settings',
          () async {
              await Navigator.push(
                  context,MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return const SettingsBiometry();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              /// call initState's property 
              loadInit();
              })
```

```
loadInit(){ ///helper metho just to make it more readable for the question
 setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    CustomerService.getCustomerInformation().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        name = value['name'];
        loading = false;
      });
    });
}
```

But while using FutureBuilder, just reassign the future variable.

Comment: All works well. Thanks a lot for saving 1,000,000 years of my life!! Best